# Is there a way to drop weapon without inventory menu?

Tags: borderlands-3

In Borderlands 1 & 2, I could drop a weapon right from my hands by pressing "-" without having to access the inventory menu. Is there a way to do this in Borderlands 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, opening the inventory is necessary. But Gearbox promised some new QoL features in the future, and that might be one of them.

Comment: Just to confirm, I think one of the previous games did not have the option to set that key in the menu, but you could still set it by editing your config files directly. Is that no longer an option for BL3 as of the time of this post?

Comment: i did not look through the config files so i cannot give you an answer to that, sry